# How to auto deposit bitcoins on btc-e?

Tags: api, btce, python

BTC-e gives a new address to send to for every time a deposit is to be made. These addressees can be accesses through this url: [Bitcoin deposit authentication required](https://btc-e.com/profile%23funds/deposit_coin/1)

I am currently using python to interact with the BTC-e server. Is there a way of doing the following automatically?

- sign into BTC-e using http request
- get new address using http request
- make a deposit to the new address
- And repeat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing in the official [documentation](https://btc-e.com/api/documentation) about this sort of thing. In the examples no-one is doing anything with deposits or withdrawals either. A quick google doesn't give any results, so I think you're stuck.

However, when I log in and want to deposit, one of the rules is the following:

> Address can be used for further deposits.

Isn't that working? Just use the same address over and over again? You will have to manually generate an address for the first time. (I know this is violating your first statement, but I used the same address at least twice for a deposit)